# Update multiple values of different nodes every second in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, updates

I am creating an app in which users earn points. Here is my data structure:

[image]

How can I update all points of different nodes by 5 every second and repeat this process?

Comment: All sounds reasonable. What's the problem that you have while implementing this use-case that you're asking for our help with?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cloud script function of Firebase as implementing this logic on client side will drain the battery as you need to update the value after every one second.

On Cloud script you can use crown job to implement this logic and it will not put any load on the application too.

Comment: Can you explain it more ? And please give me some reference link of cloud script crown job

Comment: Yes, here is the doc link

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

And here is the code 

export const scheduledFunction = 
      functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun(
          (context: EventContext) => {
            console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
            return new Promise();
     });